# Menu FAQ acordeón en html y css no cierra el contenido

Tags: html, css

Tengo un menu tipo acordeón muy sencillo en `html` y `css` que funciona muy bien pero quiero hacer que al hacer clic en el *menu 2222* o menu *3333* cierre el contenido en este caso del menu *1111* , o sea que cierre el contenido actual y abra el contenido del menu al que se le hace clic...

pero no consigo hacerlo...

He probado con distintas combinaciones de configuración en el `css` pero sin resultados positivos

***el codigo CSS***

```
main {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  font-size: clamp(20px, 4vw, 30px);
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
main {

}
summary {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #515253;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
summary:focus{
    background: #c80502;
    color: #fff;
}
summary:active {
    background: #c80502;
    color: #fff;
}
details[open] summary ~ * {
    animation: sweep .5s ease-in-out;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;

}
@keyframes sweep {
  0%    {opacity: 0; margin-top: -10px}
  100%  {opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px}
}
details > summary::after  {
  position: absolute;
  content: "+";
  right: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
details[open] > summary::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "-";
  right: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
```

***y el html***

```
<body>
  <h1>FAQ </h1>
  <main>
  <details open>
    <summary>1111</summary>
    <div class="faq__content">
      <p>11111111111 ...</p>
      <br>
    </div>
  </details>

    <details>
    <summary>2222</summary>
    <div class="faq__content">
      <p>222222222222 ...</p>
    </div>
  </details>

 <details>
    <summary>3333</summary>
    <div class="faq__content">
      <p>33333333333 ...</p>
    </div>
  </details>
   </main>
</body>
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como puedo modificar este código estaría agradecido

Gracias y saludos

Comment: No creo que una accion CSS es lo que buscas, mas parece un JS

Comment: Me parece muy interesante saber cómo le pones el attributo "open" en los elementos "details", sin usar JS. Tenía 100% claro y entendido que eso no se podía hacer sólo con CSS, sino te importa explicármelo o compartir documentación... jajaja.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente será un poco enrevesado mi código, pero la básicamente lo que se debe hacer es quitar el atributo `open` del elemento `details`, con jQuery sería menos código, pero esto sería con JS puro

```
document.querySelectorAll("details").forEach(function(detail) {
  detail.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    let me = this;
    document.querySelectorAll("details").forEach(function(element) {
      if (me != element) {
        element.removeAttribute("open")
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Espero te sea de ayuda!